# HTTP redirects to HTTPS even though on free dyno

Tags: django, heroku

For some reason, even though I'm using the free dyno, my website still redirects http to https. This is what I want to happen, but I just don't understand why it is, since doesn't this only work for paid dynos?

(I'm using Django and followed [this guide](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls) to do the redirecting.)

But why does HTTPS work at all? [Don't I need a certificate/paid dyno for that?](https://blog.heroku.com/ssl-is-now-included-on-all-paid-dynos) I'm using a Heroku subdomain.

Comment: The redirect has nothing to do with Heroku (the documentation you link to does it at the application level), but if you don't have HTTPS working your site won't load properly. Are you using a custom domain, or a Heroku subdomain like `your-app.herokuapp.com`?

Comment: But why does HTTPS work at all? Don't I need a certificate/paid dyno for that (https://blog.heroku.com/ssl-is-now-included-on-all-paid-dynos)?
I'm using a Heroku subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `.herokuapp.com` subdomain you automatically get HTTPS support, [even on free dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/understanding-ssl-on-heroku):

> SSL is **always** enabled for `.herokuapp.com` for Common Runtime apps.

You only need to use ACM, SSL, or the SSL Endpoint for custom domains. And yes, this is included with paid dynos.